# Error: Cannot find module 'ganache-cli'

Tags: contract-deployment

I am very new to programming in JavaScript and Solidity and I am trying to run a test from Windows PowerShell.

In my folder, I have all these files
[image]

I open my PowerShell window and I typed

```
npm run test
```

Where I got the error of

```
> inbox@1.0.0 test C:\inbox
> mocha


Error: Cannot find module 'ganache-cli'
Require stack:
- C:\inbox\test\Inbox.test.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inbox\test\Inbox.test.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async formattedImport (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:48:32)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:73:20)
    at async singleRun (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:366:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ramic\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-23T08_06_56_286Z-debug.log
PS C:\inbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way I solved it was by

1- Re-installing the latest version of ganache, the local test blockchain that I use to deploy my contract, develop my application in order to run the test.

```
npm install ganache-cli@latest -g
```

2- Then I re-install Node Package Manager (npm), the package manager for the JavaScript programming using

```
npm install
```

3- Then I run the test using

```
npm run test
```

Note: It is worth noting that "npm can install, in one command, all the dependencies of a project through the package.json file" Therefore, it is important to also look at the package.json file and see if there were any errors or wrong versions.

Answer (score 2):

you need to first uninstall all the dependencies first i.e.(web3, ganache-cli(which is already depricated), mocha), then use this command to install the dependencies - `npm install --save solc ganache web3 mocha`
Make sure your package.json dependencies object consist of these lines in the image also verify with the scripts. Make sure in the Inbox.test.js file you include these in the beginning - `const assert = require('assert');`, `const ganache = require('ganache');` and `const Web3 = require('web3');`
[image]
Hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 1):

Install ganache-cli in the directory by running the command `npm i ganache-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

This is another one you don't need anything to do just type it and It must be worked.

```
npx ganache-cli
```